# Reload cache of DataTables populated using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, datatables

I am using DataTables to display data in my website. In order to take advantage of it, I am using ajax to populate the table. Below is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var review = $('#review').DataTable({
        dom: 'B<"toolbar">frtip',
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'include/json_review.php',
            "data": {
               "filter" : "someFilter"
            },
            "type": 'GET',
            "dataSrc": "",
             "cache": true // to load page fast 
        }
   });
});
```

The reason why I wanted to use `cache: true` is that I'm currently loading 4500+ rows in the table which amounts to some 3.5 MB data. (I can't do without this by the way.) The data is loaded from MySQL database and is still being populated. Everything is doing well until new data is available and I'm expecting at least 20K more records. F5 (Refresh) doesn't replace the cache. Control + F5 does. I read that in most SO questions, location.reload(true) should fix the problem. So I added a button in the <"toolbar"> that runs just this, i.e.

```
$('div.toolbar').html('<button onclick="reloadData()">Refresh Data</button>'); // code inside the document.ready tags

function reloadData() {
     location.reload(true);
} // code outside document.ready tags
```

It runs but when I check the Network tab of Developer tools in Google Chrome, it shows that the data is still loaded from disk cache. I think the problem is that when I call the location.reload() function, it only loads the html but the ajax data remains the same.

One possible solution I am thinking of is to call the ajax again and pass the current timestamp as a parameter since that is what `cache: false` is supposedly doing. Is that possible? If so, how?

I'm all out of options. Help?

**Update:** I tried another approach by using table.ajax.url('include/json_review.php?_=' + time ).load() where time is $.now(). It did add data to the table but still did not replace the cache. So I basically created another cache.

**My Workaround:** I fixed my problem by overriding headers in `.htaccess`. It's a little different than what I wanted to do but I can't be picky.

```
<Files 'json_review.php'>
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=300"
</Files>
```

After five minutes, when I hit refresh or when I shift from one page to another, the browser checks for that max-age. If that max-age lapses, the ajax cache is deleted and ajax is ran again effectively replacing it.

I'll keep this posted here if anyone encounters the same problem. I would also like to know if there are better solutions.

Comment: Have you tried `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })` *then* `ajax.url('same-url-with-some-random-value').load()` ..? That should work ...

Comment: Wouldn't that disable the cache?

Comment: ?? Is that not what you want, disabling the cache when needed? Browser and server caches as well, so you must change the URL:

Comment: or reinitialise the DataTable with destroy:true and cache: false.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to control your cache,you can add a parameter like `"url":

`include/json_review.php?'+Date().getTime(),`

Normally this will reload the cache at each times the date will not be the sames

Comment: Oh. I guess my question was not clear on that. What I wanted to achieve is to let the table be displayed using cached data until the user prompts it to update. Your answer would result to updating of the table data everytime the page is loaded, no? Tl:dr I wanted to have a button that just does the updating of the cache.